# Can I specify which drive Windows uses to mount the WSL file system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have learnt how to access the WSL Ubuntu file system from Windows, but by default this is through a network share. Thus I don't know exactly where on the Windows host file system the Ubuntu file system is mounted.

I'm asking not only where it is mounted, but also if and how I can specify which Windows directory the Ubunti file system is mounted.

Comment: [mount Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/mount.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's in Windows I'm sure I'll have to do such a mounting, not in Linux. I'm asking how to mount the Linux file system _in Windows_.

Comment: No. It's done in WSL. Open a `bash` shell` and type `mount`.

Comment: @DavidPostill I know `mount` is a Linux command, and that I execute it in bash, but I'm talking about before WSL is installed, Windows must know where or how to install it. How can running `mount` help me before I can run `mount`?

Comment: It mounts it as part of the install process. I don't think there is way to specify it, but I'm not running Windows 10.